# Javascript array showing not an array Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an array of object inside another object. when i iterate this array with

```
t.schedules.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item[index]);

});
```

it shows error Uncaught TypeError: t.schedules.forEach is not a function.

but i am able to get it with t.schedules[index];

[image: please see this image]

[image: with index]

[image]

Comment: Please post more of the code. Where does `t` get populated with respect to your `forEach`?

Comment: What ever `schedules` is, it is not an array (or you're using a really old IE).

Comment: `t.schedules` may not be an array

Comment: if it is not an array how it is possible to get it with  index? i am getting data with t.schedules[0].. t.schedules[1] @ChanchalPrashantTapase

Comment: @Neha If you create object like `var a = {1: 'Hello'};` then it will also return `Hello` with `a[1]`. But `a` is `object` not `array`.

Comment: Log t.schedules not t.schedules[0] so we can see it’s structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. If `t.schedules` is an `object` then `Object.values(t.schedules)` will return `array of values` from that `object`. Then you can use `forEach`

```
if (typeof t.schedules == "object") {
    t.schedules = Object.values(t.schedules);
}
t.schedules.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item[index]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! typeof(t.schedules) returns Object

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing often happens if you try iterating before the array is populated. The logged object looks like a database entry judging by the "created_at", "updated_at" etc. keys so I'm guessing you are retrieving the array from a database? If so, check that you are waiting for the response before iterating.

Comment: yes array is populated from ajax response

Comment: That's a comment and not an answer

Comment: An answer shouldn’t be speculative. Are you sure this answer is correct?